# Find $\int_{1}^{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{n}{e^{nx}}\, dx$ , why my method doesn't work?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, power-series

I want to calculate $\int_{1}^{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{n}{e^{nx}}\, dx$ and I know the answer is $\frac{e}{e^{2}-1}$ but with my method I found something different where is my mistake?

let $\frac{n}{e^{nx}}=n(e^{-x})^{n}$ and $(e^{-x})=y \Rightarrow$ $ny^n=\frac{n}{e^{nx}}\Rightarrow$

$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty }y^n= \frac{1}{1-y}\Rightarrow $, I take the derivative with respect $y\Rightarrow$

$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty }ny^{n-1}= \frac{1}{(1-y)^2}$    $\Rightarrow $ $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty }ny^n= \frac{y}{(1-y)^2}$

$\Rightarrow$ $\int_{1}^{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{n}{e^{nx}}\, dy =\int_{1}^{2} \frac{y}{(1-y)^2}= \left [  \frac{-1}{1-y}\right ]_{1}^{2}$

and after I did some calculation, my answer was different from $\frac{e}{e^{2}-1}$ can someone explain how to solve this and why this doesn't work?

Comment: You did not change the limits of definite integral

Comment: Note that $\int_{[1,2]}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\exp(-nx)\mathrm dx = \int_{[1,2]}\int_{\mathbb N}n\exp(-nx)\mathrm dn\mathrm dx$, where $\mathrm dn$ is the counting measure. Since the integrand is nonnegative, Tonelli's theorem can be applied, i.e. $\int_{[1,2]}\int_{\mathbb N}n\exp(-nx)\mathrm dn\mathrm dx = \int_{\mathbb N}\int_{[1,2]}n\exp(-nx)\mathrm dx\mathrm dn$, which is $\int_{\mathbb N}\exp(-n)-\exp(-2n)\mathrm dn = \frac{1}{\exp(1) - 1}- \frac{1}{\exp(2) - 1} = \frac{\exp(1)}{\exp(2) - 1}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do $y=e^{-x}$, with $x$ going from $1$ to $2$, then $y$ goes from $e^{-1}$ to $e^{-2}$. Besides, if $y=e^{-x}$, then $\mathrm dy=-e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: oh yea, i see it now of course i totally forgot about that, thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.